# How to receive cmd 'quser' output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess

I am trying to build Python code that will run the quser program in cmd and will receive the output of it to then run log off to one of the users.

I tried to do it both with `os` and `subprocess` modules in Python 3.7.3, but it seems like it always says:

> 'quser' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I have also tried a full path to the `quser` executable.

```py
import os
import subprocess

output = os.system("quser")
print(output)

# returns -- > 'quser' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

p = subprocess.Popen("quser", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print(out)

# returns -- > 1 b''
```

**Expected Output**

```
USERNAME         SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLETIME  LOGON       TIME
John             console            1   Active  57        19/07/2019  12:27
Doe                                 2   Disc    57        19/07/2019  15:35
```

Comment: You don't need both `python-3.x` and `python-3.7` tags (drop `python-3.7`); you *do* need a `windows` tag, though.

Comment: Have you tried the [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function?

Comment: if I recall correctly `quser` only works from the System32 `cmd.exe` so if you are running on a x64 machine the default `cmd.exe` does not have `quser`. No idea why.

Comment: It works just fine for me on a x64 machine. Using the subprocess method I get the output you are expecting.

Comment: What do you expect `"quser"` without extension/fully qualified path (or using cmd.exe)  to expand to? Replace `"quser"` with `"C:\Windows\System32\quser.exe"`

Comment: @Alex yes, it doesn't work. it says:[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @DrBwts Yes you're right. When I try to run quser in the 32 bit cmd.exe it shows the same error that I see when I run my python program. So how can I make python use the 64 bit cmd.exe instead of the default 32 bit?

Comment: @LotPings Already tried it. said it in the question - it's not solving the problem.

Comment: cmd.exe is not the problem to solve, since you won't be able to get the output via `os.system`. You also should not be using `shell=True` to run "quser.exe"; it's not a shell command that needs cmd.exe. The problem is that you're using 32-bit Python, in which "System32" gets redirected to "SysWOW64", which doesn't have "quser.exe". If you're running 32-bit Python in 64-bit Windows 7+, use "SysNative" instead of "System32" in order to avoid the redirection.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks! found out the way to run the quest with the full path using SysNative, as well as running the program! added the script to my git for full code is someone needs it! :) Thanks for everyone! [git](https://github.com/ohaval/logoff-another-user)

Answer (score 2):

```
subprocess.check_output(r"C:\Windows\Sysnative\quser.exe")
```

really worked.